# Rails can't see my custom validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use custom validator with my Rails 3 app. Here are my files:

**app/validators/video_validator.rb**

```
class VideoValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    videoInfo = VideoInfo.new(record.video_url)
    if !videoInfo.valid?
      record.errors[:base] << "Some error message."
    end
  end
end
```

**app/models/user_video.rb**

```
class UserVideo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with VideoValidator
end
```

And now, when i'm trying to reach a `new` action from `user_videos` scaffolded controller, all i'm getting is this error:

> Routing Error uninitialized constant UserVideo::VideoValidator

I've seend a lot of tutorials on how to create custom validators and i still can't find what have i done wrong. I'll be grateful for any tips and advices :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is the validator path configured in autoload config. You can take a look here 
**[Rails 3 Custom Validator Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597347/rails-3-custom-validator-problem)**.

Also make sure to restart your server :)

Comment: yes, that was it! i was getting some strange errors without any stack trace but i forgot that sometimes it's highly recommended to restart a server :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess  you will need to include VideoValidator in your uservideo class